# Stored proc to return data based on nullable columns by a priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table called `ClientUrls` that has the following structure:

```
+------------+----------------+----------+
| ColumnName |    DataType    | Nullable |
+------------+----------------+----------+
| ClientId   | INT            | No       |
| CountryId  | INT            | Yes      |
| RegionId   | INT            | Yes      |
| LanguageId | INT            | Yes      |
| URL        | NVARCHAR(2048) | NO       |
+------------+----------------+----------+
```

I have a stored procedure `up_GetClientUrls` that takes the following parameters:

```
@ClientId INT
@CountryId INT
@RegionId INT
@LanguageId INT
```

**Information about the proc**

1. All of the parameters are required by the proc and none of them will be NULL
2. The aim of the proc is to return a single matching row in the table based on a pre-defined priority. The priority being ClientId>Country>Region>Language
3. Three of the colums in the ClientUrls table are nullable. If one column contains a NULL, it refers to "All". e.g. if LanguageId IS NULL, then it refers to "AllLanguages". So if we send a LanguageId of 5 to the proc, we look for that first, otherwise we try and find the one that is NULL.

**Matrix of priority (1 being first)**

```
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Ranking | ClientId | CountryId | RegionId | LanguageId |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
|       1 | NOT NULL | NOT NULL  | NOT NULL | NOT NULL   |
|       2 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NOT NULL | NOT NULL   |
|       3 | NOT NULL | NOT NULL  | NULL     | NOT NULL   |
|       4 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NULL     | NOT NULL   |
|       5 | NOT NULL | NOT NULL  | NOT NULL | NULL       |
|       6 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NOT NULL | NULL       |
|       7 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NULL     | NULL       |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Here is some **example data**:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+
| ClientId | CountryId | RegionId | LanguageId |             URL               |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+
|        1 |         1 | 1        | 1          | http://www.Website.com        |
|        1 |         1 | 1        | NULL       | http://www.Otherwebsite.com   |
|        1 |         1 | NULL     | 2          | http://www.Anotherwebsite.com |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

**Example stored proc call**

```
EXEC up_GetClientUrls   @ClientId = 1
                        ,@CountryId = 1
                        ,@RegionId = 1
                        ,@LanguageId = 2
```

**Expected response (based on example data)**

```
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+
| ClientId | CountryId | RegionId | LanguageId |             URL               |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+
|        1 |         1 |     NULL | 2          | http://www.Anotherwebsite.com |
+----------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

This row is returned because matching on a NULL RegionId with the correct LanguageId is a higher priority than matching on a NULL LanguageId with the correct RegionId.

Here is the code for the proc (which works). To actually get to my question, is there a better way to write this? If i extend this table in future, I'm going to just keep multiplying the number of UNION statements and therefore it isn't really scalable.

**Actual stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROC up_GetClientUrls
    (
        @ClientId       INT
        ,@CountryId     INT
        ,@RegionId      INT
        ,@LanguageId    INT
    )
AS
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1
            prioritised.ClientId
            ,prioritised.CountryId
            ,prioritised.RegionId
            ,prioritised.LanguageId
            ,prioritised.URL
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                c.ClientId
                ,c.CountryId
                ,c.RegionId
                ,c.LanguageId
                ,c.URL
                ,1  [priority]
            FROM ClientUrls c
            WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
            AND c.CountryId = @CountryId
            AND c.RegionId = @RegionId
            AND c.LanguageId = @LanguageId
            UNION
                SELECT
                    c.ClientId
                    ,c.CountryId
                    ,c.RegionId
                    ,c.LanguageId
                    ,c.URL
                    ,2  [priority]
                FROM ClientUrls c
                WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
                AND c.CountryId IS NULL
                AND c.RegionId = @RegionId
                AND c.LanguageId = @LanguageId
            UNION
                SELECT
                    c.ClientId
                    ,c.CountryId
                    ,c.RegionId
                    ,c.LanguageId
                    ,c.URL
                    ,3  [priority]
                FROM ClientUrls c
                WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
                AND c.CountryId = @CountryId
                AND c.RegionId IS NULL
                AND c.LanguageId = @LanguageId
            UNION
                SELECT
                    c.ClientId
                    ,c.CountryId
                    ,c.RegionId
                    ,c.LanguageId
                    ,c.URL
                    ,4  [priority]
                FROM ClientUrls c
                WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
                AND c.CountryId IS NULL
                AND c.RegionId IS NULL
                AND c.LanguageId = @LanguageId
            UNION
                SELECT
                    c.ClientId
                    ,c.CountryId
                    ,c.RegionId
                    ,c.LanguageId
                    ,c.URL
                    ,5  [priority]
                FROM ClientUrls c
                WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
                AND c.CountryId = @CountryId
                AND c.RegionId = @RegionId
                AND c.LanguageId IS NULL
            UNION
                SELECT
                    c.ClientId
                    ,c.CountryId
                    ,c.RegionId
                    ,c.LanguageId
                    ,c.URL
                    ,6  [priority]
                FROM ClientUrls c
                WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
                AND c.CountryId IS NULL
                AND c.RegionId = @RegionId
                AND c.LanguageId IS NULL
            UNION
                SELECT
                    c.ClientId
                    ,c.CountryId
                    ,c.RegionId
                    ,c.LanguageId
                    ,c.URL
                    ,7  [priority]
                FROM ClientUrls c
                WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
                AND c.CountryId IS NULL
                AND c.RegionId IS NULL
                AND c.LanguageId IS NULL
        ) prioritised
        ORDER BY prioritised.[Priority]

    END
```

Comment: Do your client id is unique in table? I mean if i can get `[Client_id 1 Country 1], [client_id 1, country 2]`

Comment: The ClientId, CountryId, RegionId and LanguageId should all be unique (including being unique with the NULLS).

Comment: You use `TOP 1` I should check also `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in your current code, because without knowing your indexes it isn't so obvious.

Comment: You could use CASE statements with the same permutations you have already (ie, the first one will be CASE WHEN ClientID = @@ClientID AND CountryID = @@CountryID, etc., etc.  The last one will have the 3 IS NULLs).   I *think* you will have better performance but I am not sure of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy (if i understand you correctly). You can do it with very little code. Plus it would be easy to extend if needed.

Here is a working example

```
--Make a table
CREATE TABLE #ClientUrls (ClientId INT NOT NULL,CountryId INT NULL,RegionId INT NULL,LanguageId INT NULL,URL NVARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL)

--Put some data into it
INSERT INTO #ClientUrls (ClientId, CountryId, RegionId, LanguageId, URL)
VALUES
(1,1,1,1,'http://www.Website.com'),
(1,1,1,NULL,'http://www.Otherwebsite.com'),
(1,1,NULL,2,'http://www.Anotherwebsite.com')

--This would all be in your proc
----------------------------------------------
DECLARE @ClientId       INT = 1
DECLARE @CountryId      INT = 1
DECLARE @RegionId       INT = 1
DECLARE @LanguageId     INT = 2

--This is the interesting bit
----------------------------------------------
SELECT TOP 1 C.*

FROM    #ClientUrls AS C
ORDER BY 
    --Order the ones with the best hit count near the top
   IIF(ISNULL(C.ClientId,  @ClientId)   = @ClientId  ,1,0) +            
   IIF(ISNULL(C.CountryId, @CountryId)  = @CountryId ,2,0) +
   IIF(ISNULL(C.RegionId,  @RegionId)   = @RegionId  ,4,0) +
   IIF(ISNULL(C.LanguageId,@LanguageId) = @LanguageId,8,0) DESC,

    --Order the ones with the least nulls of each hit count near the top
   IIF(C.ClientId   IS NULL,0,1) +                                              
   IIF(C.CountryId  IS NULL,0,2) +
   IIF(C.RegionId   IS NULL,0,4) +
   IIF(C.LanguageId IS NULL,0,8) DESC

DROP TABLE #ClientUrls
```

Thats it.  In older versions of SQL you cant use IIF, but you can replace that with a case statement if needed.

It works like this.

Each matching item is given a value (a bit like in a binary number)
Then based on each matching item we use the value or 0 if its not a match
by adding up the total we will always pick the best combination of matches.

```
value          1           2           4         8            Total value 
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Ranking | ClientId | CountryId | RegionId | LanguageId |
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
|       1 | NOT NULL | NOT NULL  | NOT NULL | NOT NULL   |       15
|       2 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NOT NULL | NOT NULL   |       13
|       3 | NOT NULL | NOT NULL  | NULL     | NOT NULL   |       11  
|       4 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NULL     | NOT NULL   |       9
|       5 | NOT NULL | NOT NULL  | NOT NULL | NULL       |       7
|       6 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NOT NULL | NULL       |       5
|       7 | NOT NULL | NULL      | NULL     | NULL       |       1
+---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I just updated this to make sure that you get the Non null version over a null option.

If you edit the results to return more then the top 1 you can see the items in the correct order. Ie if you change language from 2 to 1 you will get the 1,1,1,1 line Over the 1,1,1,Null option

Comment: Brilliant answer! +1 for the use of IIF as well. I hadn't come across that function yet. This query also performs better than my UNION statements.

Comment: I knew about the IIF function but I never use it because I'm 2 used to the case statement. I should really start using it. Also like splitting the NULL matches from the exact matches, makes it more maintainable. +1

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The 1,2,4,8... trick is a handy thing to keep in mind when talking about priorities. It can even work if you have two items of the same priority and it's easy to extend or retract as the numbers are only ever used in the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you could do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 c.ClientId,
        c.CountryId,
        c.RegionId,
        c.LanguageId,
        c.URL
FROM ClientUrls c
ORDER BY CASE 
            WHEN c.ClientId = @ClientId
                THEN 1000
            ELSE 0
            END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.CountryId = @CountryId
                THEN 200
            WHEN c.CountryId IS NULL
                THEN 100
            ELSE 0
            END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN c.RegionId = @RegionId
                THEN 20
            WHEN c.CountryId IS NULL
                THEN 10
            ELSE 0
            END +  
        CASE 
            WHEN c.LanguageId = @LanguageId
                THEN 2
            WHEN c.CountryId IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END DESC
```

By giving a value to each match and selecting the highest value you could reduce the code needed. But you will increase the number of case statements needed, instead of the amount of unions.

This could also be a function instead of a stored procedure. So it could be used more easier in other query's

Answer (score 0):

You can change the where clause to :

```
AND (c.CountryID = @CountryID OR c.CountryID IS NULL)
```

Coding-wise, its less code.
But tuning is much more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to try manipulating `NULL` values to create a heirarchy, something like this:

```
WITH priorities as     (SELECT
                c.ClientId
                ,c.CountryId
                ,c.RegionId
                ,c.LanguageId
                ,c.URL
                ,COALESCE(
                          NULLIF(c.CountryId,@CountryId),
                          NULLIF(c.RegionId,@RegionId),
                          NULLIF(c.LanguageId,@LanguageId),
                          1000000)
                + ISNULL(c.CountryId,200000)  
                + ISNULL(c.RegionId,100000) 
                + COALESCE(c.CountryId,RegionId,40000) 
                + ISNULL(c.LanguageId,10000) 
                + COALESCE(c.CountryId,c.LanguageId,4000) 
                + COALESCE(c.CountryId,c.RegionId,c.LanguageId,1000)
                [priority]
            FROM ClientUrls c
            WHERE c.ClientId = @ClientId
            AND (c.CountryId = @CountryId
            OR c.RegionId = @RegionId
            OR c.LanguageId = @LanguageId)
            )
SELECT TOP 1 ClientId,CountryId,RegionId,LanguageId,URL FROM priorities ORDER BY priority DESC
```